# Integral closure and field of fractions

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

I have a ring $R = \mathbb{Q}[t^2,t^5] \cong \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x,y]}{\langle x^5 - y^2 \rangle}$ (where the denominator is the ideal generated by $x^5 - y^2$). Now i have to compute the closure of $R$ in it's field of fractions.

Now would the field of fractions of $R$ be equal to $\mathbb{Q}(t^3)$ ? I say this because if we set $x=t^2$, $y=t^5$ then we have that $t^3 = y/x$. I want to go onto say that its integral closure is also $Q(t^3)$, but I am not quite sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field of fraction is $\mathbb Q(t)$, since we have $t = \frac{t^5}{(t^2)^2} \in Quot(R)$.

The integral closure is $\mathbb Q[t]$, since the normalisation of any rational curve is $\mathbb A_1$.